# How to write select so it return only one record between two time periods

Tags: sql, firebird

I have these data

```
Table: Shifts
---------------------------------
Shift_Start       Shift_End
---------------------------------
6:00              16:30
16:45             22:15
22:15             6:00 (Next day) 
----------------------------------
```

And I need to select only one record where current time is between `shift_start` and `shift_end`

for example I tried

```
Select * from Shifts where current_time between shift_start and shift_end
```

or

```
Select first 1, shift_start, shift_end from Shifts 
order by shift_end - current_time
```

but nothing worked correctly, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will do what you want:

```
Select *
from Shifts
where shift_start < shift_end and current_time between shift_start and shift_end or
      shift_start > shift_end and not current_time between shift_start and shift_end;
```

If the question is really how to get only one match:

```
Select first 1 *
from Shifts
where shift_start < shift_end and current_time between shift_start and shift_end or
      shift_start > shift_end and not current_time between shift_start and shift_end;
```

EDIT:

To return a matching time period first or then any other, you can use `order by` instead of `where`:

```
Select first 1 *
from Shifts
order by (case when shift_start < shift_end and current_time between shift_start and shift_end or
                    shift_start > shift_end and not current_time between shift_start and shift_end
               then 0 else 1
          end);
```

Comment: This is great. one thing if time is 16:40 it should return NULL but still it return one record. Can you modify so it return NULL if the time is not within any period ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax in Firebird is `ROWS 1 TO 1`. See also [SELECT Rows](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-select-rows)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Shifts 
 WHERE current_time BETWEEN shift_start AND shift_end
  ROWS 1
```